# How to bind WPF control text to boolean, and make decision about text in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a button control in a WPF application which is used for log-in purposes.  The button is dual purpose: when logged-out, it shall display the text "log in".  When logged-in, it shall display the text "log out".

I could do this with databinding to an appropriate string property in the viewmodel.
But it would be neater if I could simply databind to the "loggedIn" boolean (false for logged-out, true for logged-in) and then make the decision about what text to display on the button from within the view.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it’s possible. Check the answer I’ve posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve it using `Style` in `Xaml` without writing specific C# code.

Suppose you have `IsLoggedIn` property in `ViewModel` which is being changed on button bind command's execute method :

```
private void MyButtonCommandExecuteMethod()
{
    this.IsLoggedIn = !this.IsLoggedIn;
}

private bool isLoggedIn;
public bool IsLoggedIn
{
    get
    {
        return this.isLoggedIn;
    }

    set
    {
        this.isLoggedIn = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsLoggedIn));
    }
}
```

In the above code `OnPropertyChanged` is method implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`'s `PropertyChanged` event. If you using any framework or defined own name, then replace it with appropriate name.

You could define a style such as:

```
<Button Command="{Binding YourButtonCommand}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Log In" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLoggedIn}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Log out" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

In the above code `IsLoggedIn` is bind to `DataTrigger` to update the `Button`'s `Content` property based on it's value.

Another point, the button style is inherited from default style. If you any Keyed style then use it in `BasedOn` Property.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

Yes that is possible using value converter, specifically `IValueConverter`. You can bind a `bool` property, say `BoolProperty` from your `viewmodel` to `button` using converter like this.

```
<Button Content="{Binding BoolProperty, Converter={StaticResource BoolConverter}}" />
```

Step 1: You need to create a converter that will accept bool value and return whatever string as you wish.

```
public class BoolConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Step 2: Declare this converter as a resource in XAML (you will need to define `local` namespace alias that contains the converter in your `<Window ..>` start element.

```
<local:BoolConverter x:Key="BoolConverter" />
```

So now whenever property changed event is raised for `BoolProperty`, this converter will be triggered and `button` text will change appropriately.

**Suggestion**:

I am not sure why you think maintaining extra `string` property is not a clean way. It is clean and is much simpler approach than using converter. Whatever I have shown is unnecessary overhead for your case, IMO. However, since you asked about possibility, I detailed it. Choice is yours! :)

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion and worthy of being marked "the answer", although another answer gets at the type of solution I was thinking of when I posted the question.

I take your advice about the extra overhead.  I am very new to both WPF and MVVM, so I welcome this kind of advice from more experienced programmers.  I find in this case that I agree with you,. thanks.

Comment: Happy to help you. :)